# Conflito de Métodos e Parâmetros ao Atualizar e Salvar Funcionários em API RESTful Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

Estou desenvolvendo uma API RESTful em Java para gerenciar informações de funcionários. A API inclui operações para salvar e atualizar informações dos funcionários, com verificações para evitar a duplicação de CPF, e-mail e número de telefone. Enfrento um problema específico ao tentar atualizar os detalhes de um funcionário existente. Ao realizar uma atualização, estou enfrentando conflitos de métodos e parâmetros, o que resulta em verificações de duplicação incorretas e impede que a atualização seja concluída com sucesso.

No método de atualização (updateEmployee), estou usando a mesma lógica de verificação que uso ao salvar um novo funcionário, mas estou obtendo resultados inesperados. Em vez de verificar conflitos com outros funcionários, o sistema está detectando conflitos com o próprio funcionário que estou tentando atualizar. Isso ocorre porque estou usando o objeto employeeModel como parâmetro para as verificações de duplicação, em vez de usar o employeeId fornecido no caminho da URL. Isso faz com que as verificações erroneamente detectem conflitos com os dados do próprio funcionário em vez de outros funcionários.

Preciso de ajuda para corrigir esse problema e garantir que as verificações de duplicação sejam realizadas corretamente ao atualizar os detalhes de um funcionário existente. Agradeço antecipadamente por qualquer orientação ou sugestão para resolver esse conflito de métodos e parâmetros e permitir atualizações bem-sucedidas dos funcionários na minha API RESTful.

```
   @PostMapping("/saveEmployee")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveEmployee(@RequestBody @Valid EmployeeSaveDto employeeSaveDto, UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder) {
        if (employeeService.existsByCpf(employeeSaveDto.cpf())) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Conflict: CPF is already in use!");
        }
        if (employeeService.existsByEmail(employeeSaveDto.email())) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Conflict: Email is already in use!");
        }
        if (employeeService.existsByPhoneNumber(employeeSaveDto.phoneNumber())) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Conflict: Phone Number is already in use!");
        }
        var detailsEmployee = employeeService.saveEmployee(employeeSaveDto);
        var uri = uriBuilder.path("/employees/{addressId}").buildAndExpand(detailsEmployee.employeeId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(detailsEmployee);
    }
```

```
    @PutMapping("/{employeeId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "employeeId") UUID employeeId, @RequestBody @Valid EmployeeUpdateDto employeeUpdateDto) {
        if (employeeService.existsByCpfAndEmployeeIdNot(employeeUpdateDto.cpf(), employeeId)) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Conflict: CPF is already in use!");
        }
        if (employeeService.existsByEmailAndEmployeeId(employeeUpdateDto.email(), employeeId)) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Conflict: Email is already in use!");
        }
        if (employeeService.existsByPhoneNumberAndEmployeeId(employeeUpdateDto.phoneNumber(), employeeId)) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Conflict: Phone Number is already in use!");
        }
        try {
            employeeService.updateEmployee(employeeId, employeeUpdateDto);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(employeeService.findEmployeeById(employeeId));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

```
    public boolean existsByCpfAndEmployeeIdNot(String cpf, UUID employeeId) {
        return employeeRepository.existsByCpfAndEmployeeId(cpf, employeeId);
    }

    public boolean existsByEmailAndEmployeeId(String email, UUID employeeId) {
        return employeeRepository.existsByEmailAndEmployeeId(email, employeeId);
    }

    public boolean existsByPhoneNumberAndEmployeeId(String phoneNumber, UUID employeeId) {
        return employeeRepository.existsByPhoneNumberAndEmployeeId(phoneNumber, employeeId);
    }

    public boolean existsByCpf(String cpf) {
        return employeeRepository.existsByCpf(cpf);
    }

    public boolean existsByEmail(String email) {
        return employeeRepository.existsByEmail(email);
    }

    public boolean existsByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        return employeeRepository.existsByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    }
```

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeModel, UUID> {

    boolean existsByCpfAndEmployeeId(String cpf, UUID employeeId);

    boolean existsByEmailAndEmployeeId(String email, UUID employeeId);

    boolean existsByPhoneNumberAndEmployeeId(String phoneNumber, UUID employeeId);

    boolean existsByCpf(String cpf);

    boolean existsByEmail(String email);

    boolean existsByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
}
```

[Requisição para salvar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGeH9.png)

[Requisição para editar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiap9.png)

Comment: Olá! Vejo que está utilizando o UUID do funcionário. Isso faz com que você olhe somente para esse registro. Se a ideia é varrer a base para verificar conflitos, seria importante criar um método para verificar a lista. Tem varias forma de fazer. Ou via query dinâmica, ou via stream, mas não será possível usar os mesmos métodos de inserir.